# Google's reCaptcha g-recaptcha-response

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-applications, captcha

I have a brief question regarding Google's captcha service.

I want to know whether it is possible to solve a captcha and retrieve the response token for a specific site key, even if the website in question isn't displaying it explicitly for the user.

For example, in order to register at the following link, I need to successfully solve the captcha:

https://wordpress.org/support/register.php

Imagine that the captcha was removed, but I still wanted to get the g-recaptcha-response token for solving it on that domain. If it is possible, how would I go about doing that?